# (Excel VBA) write formula for the whole column

Tags: vba, formula

I have 30 excel files need to be done with the same operation. I have non-fixed number of rows in my excel files. For all excel files, I want to apply VBA to write IF function into the column"H" from the second row to the last row.

Here is the formula I need to write (for the second row): =IF(AND(C2=C3,C2=C1,G2=TRUE,G1=FALSE,G3=TRUE),"O",IF(AND(C2=C3,C2<>C1,G2=TRUE),"FromYes",IF(AND(C2=C1,C2=C3,G2=TRUE,G1=TRUE,G3=FALSE),"D",IF(AND(C2=C1,C2<>C3,G2=TRUE),"ToTmr",""))))

Other rows shall have similar formula.

Is there any way for me to write a formula directly in vba for the whole column "H"?

I have tried some code like this, but it run extremely slow

```
For x = 2 To lastRow

If ws.Cells(x, 3) = ws.Cells(x + 1, 3) And ws.Cells(x, 3) = ws.Cells(x - 1, 3) And ws.Cells(x, 7) = True And ws.Cells(x - 1, 7) And ws.Cells(x + 1, 7) = True Then
ws.Cells(x, 8) = "O"

Else

If Cells(x, 3) = Cells(x + 1, 3) And (Cells(x, 3) <> Cells(x - 1, 3)) And Cells(x, 7) = True Then

Cells(x, 8) = "FromYes"

Else

If Cells(x, 3) = Cells(x - 1, 3) And Cells(x, 3) = Cells(x + 1, 3) And Cells(x, 7) = True And Cells(x - 1, 7) = True And Cells(x + 1, 7) = False Then

Cells(x, 8) = "D"

Else

If Cells(x, 3) = Cells(x - 1, 3) And Cells(x, 3) <> Cells(x + 1, 3) And Cells(x, 7) = True Then

Cells(x, 8) = "ToTmr"

End If

End If

End If

End If


Next x

Next d
```

Comment: Please write out the conditions in English. What do you want to happen IF ....

Comment: Why not record a macro when inputting the formula into the spreadsheet. Itt will give the you the .FormulaR1C1 or  Range formula you need. This would be much simpler than what you are doing with the code. Also,code as shown, can this not be reduced to one IF statement with 3 ElseIFs and also all Cells be consistently referred to as ws.Cells if they are indeed in the same worksheet. Identing the code properly was also help.

Comment: do you have sample data?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things to change in your approach. Firstly, use the fact that you can set cell formulas with VBA. Secondly, use the fact that you can set cell formulas for an entire range in VBA. Thirdly, if your formula is fast, use it instead of code (this is not a hard and fast rule, but if you're new to VBA or not using it often, it's simpler to use formulas).

Using those ideas, I came up with this:

```
With Sheet1
    .Range(.Cells(2, 8), .Cells(lastRow, 8)).FormulaR1C1 = _
            "=IF(AND(RC[-5]=R[1]C[-5],RC[-5]=R[-1]C[-5],RC[-1],NOT(R[-1]C[-1]),R[1]C[-1]),""O""," & _
            "IF(AND(RC[-5]=R[1]C[-5],RC[-5]<>R[-1]C[-5],RC[-1]),""FromYes""," & _
            "IF(AND(RC[-5]=R[1]C[-5],RC[-5]=R[-1]C[-5],RC[-1],R[-1]C[-1],NOT(R[1]C[-1])),""D""," & _
            "IF(AND(RC[-5]<>R[1]C[-5],RC[-5]=R[-1]C[-5],RC[-1]),""ToTmr"",""""))))"
End With
```

This is setting the formula for the range of column H, rows 2 through the lastRow, for Sheet1 equal to your formula. The removes the need to loop rows, making it much quicker.

I always find it is easier to work with R1C1 format when entering formulas through VBA. It's easy enough to get that format; you just need to go the formula options in Excel and select R1C1 Reference Style. Then you can copy it into the VBA and escape quotation marks with another quotation mark.

Using this, you can easily write a tool that loops through the files, finds the last row on the appropriate sheet, and sets the formula.